# ActiveRecord Grouping and associated fields

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

Suppose I have a Relationship table documenting relationships between users and mentors. I want to retrieve the **newest** (i.e. latest) mentor for each user.

```
Relationship.selects("MAX(id) AS newest_relationship_id").group('user_id')
```

This successfully returns, as column newest_relationship_id, the newest relationship for each user, but how do I ensure that the therapist_id column will return the correct corresponding therapist for that newest relationship?

Comment: Do you have a `mentors` table and a `mentor_id` column in `relationships`, or are they named something different?

Comment: @PinnyM yes exactly. Relationships columns are simply id, mentor_id, user_id

Comment: Also, can you be a bit more specific on the structure of the result you are looking for?  Do you want a hash as `user => newest_mentor` or something else?

Comment: What I'm looking for is to find, for each mentor, all of the mentor's current users. Current users are the newest relationships only. So for mentor X I want to find all the users who have mentor X as their newest mentor relationship.

Comment: This can certainly be done, but you may want to rethink your schema.  If you are using a MAX value to represent a concrete relationship, your queries are not going to perform well when your tables grow larger.  Have you considered marking the most recent user relationship with a boolean flag (clearing all existing flags for that user in before_create)?

Comment: @PinnyM that is what I'm debating - if I should add a flag or not. Will probably add one for performance, as you point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect the new-relationship ids for a specific mentor and use those in your subquery:

```
mentor = Mentor.find(mentor_id) 
newest_relationship_ids = Relationship.select("MAX(id)").group(:user_id)
mentor.relationships.
       includes(:user).                       # eager load the user
       where(:id => newest_relationship_ids).
       map(&:user)                            # collect the user
```

You can also do this a bit more efficiently using a subquery:

```
mentor = Mentor.find(mentor_id) 
newest_relationship_ids = Relationship.select("MAX(id)").group(:user_id).to_sql
mentor.relationships.
       includes(:user).         
       where("relationships.id IN (#{newest_relationship_ids}).
       map(&:user)
```

Comment: In the first answer if you add the where clause, wont it limit the result set to the mentor only? which means sql won't even include the other mentor relationships. so if the newest relationship is of another mentor, it won't be included at all in the result set, and it will incorrectly return the mentor_id as the newest mentor.

Comment: I like the second answer, was thinking of doing that, though I would use .pluck(:id) instead of .to_sql

Comment: @DavidLesches: In the second answer, the whole point was to avoid making 2 queries.  `to_sql` helps you do this as one query.